# Piping cat to sendmail not respecting new lines

Tags: bash, cat, sendmail

I have a script which runs a few sanity checks, outputs the results to a file which is then concatenated and piped to a `sendmail` function as so:

`{ echo "$headers"; echo; cat health_check.log; } | sendmail "$recipients" ;`

If I `cat` the file the output is the result of the sanity checks on some 40 lines. When I receive the email the body of the text is all on one line and consequently hard to read.

How do I ensure new lines are respected?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the file `health_check.log` so we can try to reproduce your problem ?

Comment: Perhaps your mail reading program is at fault. Some readers will assume lines ending with a space should be concatenated to the next line, so ensure your data has no trailing whitespace on each line.

Comment: Off the top of my head it doesn't look like you are doing anything to format the email. I think email uses CRLF line breaks instead of just LF.  Sendmail won't format the email, only send it.